# How to add a Button below a List in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, list, button, swiftui

how can I add a Button in SwiftUI below a List so that it looks like in the Note app:
[image]

I tried it with a Stack but this did not work.

Comment: Can you share your code please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is simple demo:

```
struct DemoListWithButton: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                List(0..<100) { i in
                    Text("Item \(i)")
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Title")
                Button("Button") {}
                    .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DemoListWithButton_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DemoListWithButton()
    }
}
```